# Why can't I deduce template argument for this function?

Tags: c++, templates

I try to make a function template, remove a Value from a vector, giving a Key:

```
template
<
    typename Value,
    typename Map,
    typename Key
>
void RemoveValue(
    Map& m, 
    const Key& k, 
    const Value& v,
    std::function<bool(const Value&)> f)
{
    auto it1 = m.find(k);
    if (it1 == m.end())
    {
        return;
    }
    auto vs = it1->second;
    auto it2 = std::find_if(vs.begin(), vs.end(), f);
    if (it2 == vs.end())
    {
        return;
    }
    vs.erase(it2);
    if (vs.empty())
    {
        m.erase(it1);
    }
}
```

When I use it:

```
RemoveValue(entityToTags, &entity, tag, [&](const Tag& t){ return t == tag; });
```

With:

```
const Entity& entity, const Tag& tag

std::map<const Entity*, std::vector<Tag>> entityToTags;
```

I must specify `Tag`, i.e. `RemoveValue<Tag>(entityToTags, &entity, tag, [&](const Tag& t){ return t == tag; });` to successfully compile.

**How can I not explicitly specify `<Tag>`, and let the compiler know it?**

I am using VS2012.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely there's a difference between `X` and `std::vector<X>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply take an `f` of arbitrary type, instead of forcing it into `std::function`. It makes more sense, as it could even be fore efficient, and the standard library does that extensively. So change the function like this:

```
template
<
    typename Value,
    typename Map,
    typename Key,
    typename Functor
>
void RemoveValue(
    Map& m, 
    const Key& k, 
    const Value& v,
    Functor f)
{
    auto it1 = m.find(k);
    if (it1 == m.end())
    {
        return;
    }
    auto vs = it1->second;
    auto it2 = std::find_if(vs.begin(), vs.end(), f);
    if (it2 == vs.end())
    {
        return;
    }
    vs.erase(it2);
    if (vs.empty())
    {
        m.erase(it1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the error message to your question...

Anyway, I used CLang++ to compile it and the error is:

```
test.cpp:47:5: error: no matching function for call to 'RemoveValue'
    RemoveValue(entityToTags, &entity, tag, [&](const Tag &t) { return t == tag; });
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:15:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<bool (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against '<lambda at t.cpp:47:45>'
void RemoveValue(
```

That is, to deduce the type of `Tag` the compiler must use the 3rd argument `tag` and the 4th. The last one is of type `std::function<bool(const Value&)>` but you pass a lambda. Yes, the lambda is convertible to that type, but it is *not* that type, so the automatic deduction for `Tag` fails.

The solution would be to pass a value of real type `std::function<bool(const Value&)>`:

```
std::function<bool(const Tag&)> f = [&](const Tag &t) { return &t == &tag; };
RemoveValue(entityToTags, &entity, tag, f);
```

Or use `static_cast<>()`, if you prefer, but I would find that line too long.

Comment: I get it, but my compile error didnt mention about the lambda, so I didnt think of that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MarsonMao: I guessed so, CLang++ error messages are so much better. Anyway it is a good practice in SO to copy the compiler message even if it looks useless.