# why this code have C2784 "could not deduce template argument" error

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, function-pointers

From [Lambda function passed as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703240/lambda-function-passed-as-parameter) I can compile the example:

```
template <class Range>
Range FindFirstIf(Range, bool(*Function)(typename Range::ConstReference value));

struct range {  using ConstReference = const float&; };

range rng;
rng = FindFirstIf(rng, [](const float& val) { return (val < 0.0f); });
```

Of course it can't link as `FindFirstIf` is not implemented.

However, when I did a similar thing:

```
template <class Range, class ValueType>
Range MyTest(Range, ValueType, bool(*Function)(ValueType value));

std::vector <int> vi;
double d = 0;
vi =       MyTest(vi, d, [](double val) { return (val < 0.0f); });
```

It has compilation error:

> error C2784: 'Range MyTest(Range,ValueType,bool (__cdecl
>   *)(ValueType))' : could not deduce template argument for 'bool (__cdecl *)(ValueType)' from
>   'main::'

why so? I thought by passing `d` in, `ValueType` can be deduced as `double`?

Comment: Not sure if it's because the type of `[](double val) { return (val < 0.0f); }` does not equal to `bool(*Function)(ValueType value)`. I've got a similar question before, maybe you can check it out. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606517/why-cant-i-deduce-template-argument-for-this-function

Comment: If they are the same problem, the key point is that to deduce `ValueType`, it requires `ValueType` and `bool(*Function)(ValueType value)` to be both matched, but the type of lambda may be not match `bool(*Function)(ValueType value)` (i.e. they are convertible, but not equal)

Comment: `vi = MyTest<std::vector<int>, double>(vi, d, [](double val) { return (val < 0.0f); });` will work!!

Comment: @Praveen It works because deduction doesn't take place, but you have to explicitly specify the type and I suspect it is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead (note the `+`):

```
vi = MyTest(vi, d, +[](double val) { return (val < 0.0f); });
```

Lambda functions can decay to function pointers in some cases, but **they are not** function pointers for themselves.
In other terms, deduction fails because it expects to work on a function pointer, but the lambda is not a function pointer, it could be converted of course, but first of all deduction must take place, but it cannot for the lambda is not the *expected type*, it could decay to it ... And so on.
By adding the `+` in front of the lambda, you force the conversion before it is passed to the function, thus `MyTest` receives an actual function pointer as expected and deduction goes on.

Here is a minimal, working example based on your code:

```
#include<vector>

template <class Range, class ValueType>
Range MyTest(Range, ValueType, bool(*Function)(ValueType value)) {}

int main() {
    std::vector <int> vi;
    double d = 0;
    vi = MyTest(vi, d, +[](double val) { return (val < 0.0f); });
}
```

Comment: Hi is there any documentation about the '+'? I'd like to know more, thanks!

Comment: @MarsonMao The working draft, cppreference.com, and so on. It is standard C++.

Comment: @MarsonMao Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this?rq=1